# For-loop calling urllib.urlopen().getcode() is slow

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, for-loop, urllib

I have a program in Python that runs through all combinations of a string (which are saved in the list `comb`) and checks if the website belonging to it exists. The program works but it runs very slowly. After trying out a few things, I think the problem is the `getcode` method, because all the other parts work fast except for that line. How can I make this program faster?

It uses less then 1% of my CPU and very little of my internet bandwidth. I tried running 3 instances of the program at once and each worked as fast as if I only ran one of them. Is it possible to replicate this in the program?

```
for p in comb: 
    if urllib.urlopen(url + p).getcode()!=404:
        print "Sucessful: " + str(p)
        break
    else:
        print "Failure:" + str(p)
```

Comment: I think if you're waiting for a response from the website, your wait time doesn't have to do with Python or the speed at which the script runs.

Comment: You can utilise threads which do the `urlopen` in parallel.

Comment: @septi: Can you give me a bit of a hint on how to run them parallel? I read about multiprocessing, can I use that?

Comment: Read some tutorials on multithreading. There are several approaches to achieve what you want…

Comment: You can also add ``timeout`` to ``urlopen`` if you can allow yourself discarding slow responses. The problem you have comes from the fact that connection attempt is a blocking operation, hence it either succeeds or waits for the global timeout before continuing. Of course, this is all relative to the number of urls and discards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to multithreading is using asynchronous requsts. You can use `grequests`, a variation of the `requests` library coupled with `Gevent`, to do this. Using code from the [Github page itself](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://python-tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)

for i in grequests.imap(rs):
    print i, i.url
```

Result on my end is a nifty 7 seconds.

```
<Response [200]> http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/
<Response [200]> https://www.heroku.com/
<Response [200]> http://httpbin.org/
<Response [200]> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/
<Response [200]> http://www.kennethreitz.org/
[Finished in 7.0s]
```

My take on a multithreaded approach.

```
import requests as rq
import threading

urls = ["...={}".format(x) for x in range(100)]

def get_status(url):
    if rq.get(url, verify=False).status_code != 404:
        print "Successful: {}\n".format(url)
    else:
        print "Failed: {}".format(url)

for url in urls:
    t = threading.Thread(None, get_status, url, (url,))
    t.start()
```

This was able to get the status of 100 websites in about 10 seconds.

Comment: My old programm only took 1/3 of a second but I need a faster one. But this could be the solution anyways.

Comment: 1 URL in 0.3 seconds. Or 3 URLs in 1 second.

Comment: Added my own multithreaded approach, similar to @T90's answer. Kindly test it on your end.

Comment: @KarlKastor: Gratitude is better expressed by accepting my answer. This can be done by clicking on the check mark next to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Using Thread would be a possible solution

```
from Threading import Thread

def checkresponse(p):
    if urllib.urlopen(p).getcode()!=404:
        print "Sucessful: " + str(p)
    else:
        print "Failure:" + str(p)

for p in comb: 
    t = Thread(target ="checkresponse", args=(p,))
    t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but i get the error "break outside loop". Also shouldnt it be Thread(target ="checkresponse", args = p)?

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove the break, as I had copied your code as such. edited.

Comment: "checkresponse() needs exactly 1 argument, 5 given" ? Okay,

Comment: @KarlKastor target should be the function object, not a string. and the args parameter will be expanded, so you should send it in a tuple ideally `args=(p,)`

Comment: somehow the input strings for checkresponse are gettin longer and longer. That's very strange.

Comment: Change `urlib.urlopen(url + p)` to `urlib.urlopen(p)`